# Test If An NSString Contains a Letter

Tags: iphone

I'm working on an iPhone project and I need to check if the user's input in a `UITextfield` contains a letter. More generally if an `NSString` contains a letter.

I tried this with a giant if loop with the `rangeofstring:@"A".location == NSNotFound` and then did OR `rangeofstring:@"B".location == NSNotFound`

and so on....

But:

1. It doesn't seem to work
2. There has to be a simple line of code to check if the NSString contains letters.

I have been searching this for hours... Can someone please answer this question???

Answer (score 12):

Use an `NSCharacterSet`. Note that `letterCharacterSet` includes all things that are "letters" or "ideographs." So that includes é and 中, but usually that's what you want. If you want a specific set of letters (like English letters), you can construct your own `NSCharacterSet` with them using `characterSetWithCharactersInString:`.

```
if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]].location == NSNotFound)
```

Comment: Should it not be `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:`?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to make sure the text has a certain letter in it (as opposed to just ANY letter),  use the `rangeOfString:` message. For example, to ensure the text contains the letter "Q":

```
NSString *string = @"poQduu";


if  ([string rangeOfString:@"Q"].location != NSNotFound) {
    DLog (@"Yes, we have a Q at location %i", [string rangeOfString:@"Q"].location );
}
```

As others (Rob Napier) note, if you want to find ANY letter, use the `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:` message.

```
if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound) ...
```